# The most simple way getting rid of MS16-004?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, update

As most of us know by now, the fix **MS16-004** broke SharePoint's listviews, especially the update **KB3124585** that could be installed on it's own without the rest of the January 2016 CU from windows update.

[Security Patch MS16-004 (KB3124585) Breaks SharePoint 2013](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=616)

Learned things the hard way, i only patch SharePoint when something is broken and a CU/fix clearly states that it fixes the issue (besides security updates of course).

My problem right now is that our global security policies demands that this broken security fix get's installed ASAP.

I want to take a minimalist way and install the least amount of patches required to get get rid of **KB3124585** in windows update.

Would installing the fix mentioned in [Stefan Goßners](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/01/15/solution-for-the-list-view-issue-with-ms16-004-january-2016-pu-for-sharepoint-2013/) blog be enough? Or do i need to apply the full 2016 January cumulative update? And i don't wanna apply KB3124585 at all if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what Stefan posted is enough to fix the issue. Installing the Jan CU or newer would also resolve the issue.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Guess i have to wait another 13 minutes to accept this as an answer. Thanks!